# How to display controllers with proper aligning in iPhone screen?

Tags: iphone

I have a issue of displaying information in iPhone screen.  Case is as follows.

1. I crated a view-based application in Xcode name as myView.
2. Then open myViewViewController.xib interface builder, change back
   groung color and added label at top-let (0, 0) of the view.
3. Then I add new file named as myView2ViewController, which is subclass of UIViewController and corresponding XIB also generated.
4. Open myView2ViewController in IB and added a label at top-left as previous. Also changed the background color.
5. In the "applicationDidFinishLaunching" of AppDeligate do following

   myView2ViewController *mView = [[myView2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myView2ViewController" bundle:nil];

   [window addSubview:mView.view];

When I run the application, it is shown as upper part of the Label is sheared. It seems as whole UI has been moved 20 px upper (Because, there is a horizontal space in the bottom). I guess this is due to some positioning. But still I could not found any way to fix it.

Hope somebody will help me to identify this issue !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your simulated user interface components in IB. You probably want Status-bar Gray, Top-bar, bottom-bar unspecified. Also check your view lengths are correct : 320x460 if you have a status bar.

Personally, I'd have architected this so that I add mView to myViewController in (say) viewDidLoad, rather than adding it to the window in appDelegate and I'd set mView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);